# automation error in access vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm using below code to make connection and execute the query but it not working properly it shows "Auomation error unspecified error"
the code is :

```
On Error GoTo err
    DoCmd.Hourglass (True)

    'For Report file Name
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strReportFileName As String
    Dim rsReportFileName As New ADODB.Recordset
    strReportFileName = ""

    Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection

    sSql = ""
    sSql = "SELECT * from tblInputFile as input inner join tblAccountMst as actmaster on input.Account=actmaster.AccountAsPerBOI"

    If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
    rs.Open sSql, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic **'on this line i get the error and it goes to catch block** 

    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        If FE.FolderExists(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Reports\") = False Then
           FE.CreateFolder (Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Reports\")
        End If
err:
    MsgBox "Error " & err.Description
    DoCmd.Hourglass (False)
```

please help im beginner in Access VBA. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INPUT` is a reserved word in Access SQL, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx#daidxsqli) or [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe#__toc272229040)

Put it in square brackets

```
sSql = "SELECT * from tblInputFile as [input] inner join tblAccountMst as actmaster on [input].Account=actmaster.AccountAsPerBOI"
```

or better: use a different alias.